# Caption outside table?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to add a caption to a table in latex, however it throws this error "! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float."
From the error I am guessing it means that it is outside the table, but I have clearly put it inside.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Table1}
Potentiometer & Resistance  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Calculated V\textsubscript{32}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Measured V\textsubscript{32}}\\ \cline{3-6}
Position & R\textsubscript{34} & Amplitude & Phase & Amplitude & Phase\\ \hline \hline
1 & 303.8 & & 2.73 & 28.2 & 2.51\\
2 & 1.141k & & 1.81 & 28.2 & 1.63\\
3 & 3.453k & & 0.79 & 28.2 & 0.5\\
4 & 5.33k & & 0.53 & 28.2 & 0.38\\
5 & 7.45k & & 0.38 & 28.2 & 0.25\\
6 & 9.54k & & 0.30 & 28.2 & 0.13\\
7 & 10.84k & & 0.27 & 28.2 & 0.13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The tabular environment won't take a caption. You need to do something like this:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
Potentiometer & Resistance  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Calculated V\textsubscript{32}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Measured V\textsubscript{32}}\\ \cline{3-6}
Position & R\textsubscript{34} & Amplitude & Phase & Amplitude & Phase\\ \hline \hline
1 & 303.8 & & 2.73 & 28.2 & 2.51\\
2 & 1.141k & & 1.81 & 28.2 & 1.63\\
3 & 3.453k & & 0.79 & 28.2 & 0.5\\
4 & 5.33k & & 0.53 & 28.2 & 0.38\\
5 & 7.45k & & 0.38 & 28.2 & 0.25\\
6 & 9.54k & & 0.30 & 28.2 & 0.13\\
7 & 10.84k & & 0.27 & 28.2 & 0.13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table1}
\label{tab:xyz}
\end{table}
```

Comment: +1. Stick a \label{} in there while your at it. It rotten style to put in a float and not refer to it at least once.

Comment: I moved the caption to the bottom because that's where it's expected by default (the spacing will be wrong otherwise). If you want to move it to the top, look at the caption package.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to use a "float" (e.g. table or figure) that will "float away" from the place you define it, you can add:

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
```

in the preamble and then do something like:

```
\begin{center}
  \captionof{table}{Caption text goes here}
  \label{table1} % for use in \ref{table1} if you want to refer to the table number
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  % etc.
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

to add a auto-numbered caption to a non-float.

Comment: New one by me. I would discourage this in general---TeX knows a *lot* about good layout---but it is nice to know its there.

Comment: Again, don't forget to ensure that the spacing of the caption is correct for being placed above the tabular; by default it's expected below.

Comment: This was actually really helpful to me, I needed to add a caption to a table in a special single column environment, within a two column document. The single column environment I was using wouldn't take a tabular but it would take a table, thus you can use this with decent results. Agree with dmckee, generally discourage it though.

Comment: thanks for mentioning captionof.
how is it bad layout to name a table which is not floating? it is a mistake not to list a (large) table in the list of tables.

Comment: the `caption` package offers the same functionality to use a caption outside a floating environment